# Calculated date column not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

I have a list that show all our clients and a date column called 'Last Visit' and another date column called 'Next Visit'

I then have a calculated column to work out how many days it's been since we last visited the client

This is the calculation =IF(Last="","",TODAY()-Last)

For some reason it not working all the time, see the screenshot below taken 10 today, you can see the item highlighted, it shows the last visit was 13th November but the days since visit is 0

Any ideas what's wrong with the calulation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calculated fields are not dynamic. The values are evaluated during the item is created or updated. Hence in your case [Today]'s value got evaluated as the date the record last updated.

If you are looking for dynamic results then you need to use

1. Daily running timer job
2. Daily running workflow
3. Update list view and calculate dynamically
4. Use JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I setup the daily workflow?

Comment: You can use Delay Activity and a loop in SharePoint designer 2013

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how would I set this up in SPD?

Comment: Any help with this would be great

Comment: @MattSaunders you can look in internet for (1)Running a daily workflow in SPD (2)Using workflow to update list item fields